# css transition and translate bug

Tags: html, css, transition, translate

i'm developing a website, and i have a bug as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we0m8s91/).

My footer, on hover, should go up, and on "mouse-out" should go back to his place, but if i go out, and place the mouse where it went after going up, the footer automatically goes up without the smooth effect ...

I can't explain this in other easier way, so if someone understands and knows how to help, i really appreciate!

Here is the same code:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.x{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.y{
    background-color: #ABC;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:-50px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in;
    transition: 1s ease-in;
}
.y:hover{
    -webkit-transition: ease;
    -moz-transition: ease;
    -ms-transition: ease;
    -o-transition: ease;
    transition: ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px,-100px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px,-100px);
    transform: translate(0px,-100px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="x"> x
    </div>
    <div class="y"> y
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code here? (Also linking to the fiddle is fine.) Without the code here, when that fiddle gets changed or deleted in the future, this question will not make any sense anymore.

Comment: sorry, never posted a fiddle :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a timing value for the transition on hover

```
transition: 0.5s ease;
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we0m8s91/1/);

Comment: holy moly, thanks, i think i tried that, or something very similar but didn't achieve this outcome...

Thank you!